# Trying to set child component's height to ancestors height

Tags: css, angular

I have components set up that render as shown in the image below.

[image]

This is MainComponent which renders the div with class 'content'

```
<shared-top-control-bar></shared-top-control-bar>
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<shared-footer-bar></shared-footer-bar>
```

The div with class content is reported properly with a height of 907px.

When the PointOfSale (app-point-of-sale) component is rendered, it's content is about 6.4k px in height and so app-point-of-sale has a height of 6.4k px. So when setting the height of the pos-wrapper div to 100%, it sets the height to 6.4k px when I really want it to be 907px.

I'm pretty new to CSS and angular. I could just use a service to track the height and inject the service to the components that need it. Just looking to see if there is a CSS way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the CSS of the `PointOfSale` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the nested component if you make a div which has the style of 100% it will take the height of the parent container.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17vrmg
Take a look at this example.